# Unable to use "window.ethereum" in Angular

Tags: metamask, angular2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from '@metamask/providers';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-connect-wallet',
  templateUrl: './connect-wallet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./connect-wallet.component.css'],
})
export class ConnectWalletComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private window: Window) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  connectWallet() {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
    }
  }
}
```

I create a component like this to get metamask and I'm constantly getting error:

```
Cannot find module '@metamask/providers' or its corresponding type declarations.

Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

Can anybody who can access to metamask with using Angular show me the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum: any;
  }
}
```